# Pandas.rolling().median vs Scipy.signal.medfilt()

Tags: pandas, scipy, filtering, signal-processing, smoothing

I applied `Pandas.rolling().median()`, and it has a **delay** or **phase shift** (green line).

If I use `Scipy.signal.medfilt()` the results are not shifted (yellow line).

[image]

**Why, the results are not the same?**

P.S. I've tried to look into *medfilt* implementation, which uses sigtools._order_filterND, which I assume is not in python.

**CODE:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import medfilt

x = np.zeros(100)
x[30:70] = 2
x+= .1 * np.random.randn(100)

y1 = medfilt(x, kernel_size=5)

plt.plot(x, '.-', label='original signal');
plt.plot(y1, '.-', alpha=.5, label='medfilt'); 
plt.plot(pd.Series(x).rolling(5).median(), label='rolling window');
plt.legend();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to center the window while rolling?

```
Pandas.rolling(center=True).median()
```